# React Native Form Validation Methodology

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am very new to React Native. I am trying to create a fully functional login screen using some custom form validation methods. I am getting stocked with the form validation now due to the fact that setState method in react is asynchronous. Seeing my below code, can someone please recommend me what's the best practice.

I want the user journey as described below

The user puts his/her email address and password, and as they click on SignUp Button, I will validate the input and if there is an error, I will setState my error and will show the error message. If my state is equal to the empty string, which will mean that there is no validation error and I can proceed with my operation. Below is the entire Register Screen Code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Content,
  H1,
  Form,
  Item,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button,
  Text,
  Icon,
} from 'native-base';
import {globalStyles} from '../../helper/globalStyles';
import {
  vaidateEmailAddress,
  validatePassword,
} from '../../helper/validationfunctions';

const RegisterScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const [emailInputError, setEmailInputError] = useState(null);
  const [emailInputErrorMessage, setEmailInputErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [passwordInputError, setPasswordInputError] = useState(null);
  const [passwordInputErrorMessage, setPasswordInputErrorMessage] = useState(
    '',
  );

  return (
    <Container style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Content contentContainerStyle={globalStyles.content}>
        <H1>Register</H1>
        <H1 />
        <Form>
          <Item error={emailInputError} style={globalStyles.item}>
            <Label>Email</Label>
            <Input
              onChangeText={text => {
                setEmail(text);
              }}
            />
          </Item>
          {emailInputError && (
            <Item style={globalStyles.erroritem}>
              <Icon name="ios-close-circle" style={{color: 'red'}} />
              <Text style={globalStyles.erroritemText}>
                {emailInputErrorMessage}
              </Text>
            </Item>
          )}
          <Item error={passwordInputError} style={globalStyles.item}>
            <Label style={globalStyles.labelText}>Password</Label>
            <Input
              style={globalStyles.input}
              onChangeText={text => {
                setPassword(text);
              }}
            />
          </Item>

          {passwordInputError && (
            <Item style={globalStyles.erroritem}>
              <Icon name="ios-close-circle" style={{color: 'red'}} />
              <Text style={globalStyles.erroritemText}>
                {passwordInputErrorMessage}
              </Text>
            </Item>
          )}

          <Item style={(globalStyles.item, globalStyles.lastItem)} last>
            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                //First Validate Empty Field
                if (
                  email === '' ||
                  email === null ||
                  !vaidateEmailAddress(email)
                ) {
                  setEmailInputError('error');
                  console.log('Value changed' + emailInputError);
                  setEmailInputErrorMessage(
                    'The email you provided is not a valid email address',
                  );

                  console.log(email === '');
                  console.log(email === null);
                  console.log(vaidateEmailAddress(email));
                }
                if (
                  password === '' ||
                  password === null ||
                  !validatePassword(password)
                ) {
                  setPasswordInputError('error');
                  setPasswordInputErrorMessage(
                    'The password you provided is not a valid password',
                  );
                }
                setTimeout(() => {
                  if (emailInputError === null && passwordInputError === null) {
                    console.log(
                      'Email: ' +
                        emailInputError +
                        ' Password: ' +
                        passwordInputError +
                        ' I am fired',
                    );
                    // TODO: Add firebase code
                  }
                }, 100);

                navigation.navigate('RegisterScreen');
              }}>
              <Text>Signup</Text>
            </Button>
          </Item>

          <Item style={(globalStyles.item, globalStyles.lastItem)} last>
            <Button
              bordered
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.pop();
              }}>
              <Text>Go Back</Text>
            </Button>
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing and validating forms can be a pain :(
I recommend using a third party library to make your life easier. One of the best libraries for React Native is Formik. You can find the docs for React Native integrations [here](https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will it work with native base. I am not using standard RN components

Comment: @HammadHaneefPasha yes, I think you can :) check out this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499741/formik-validation-for-native-base-input - it explains how to use Formik in the context of native base.